# Adapting Skip32 to a 31-bit block Cipher

Tags: ruby, encryption, bitwise-operators

So here's a ruby implementation of Skip32 by patdeegan:

https://github.com/patdeegan/integer-obfuscator/blob/master/lib%2Fcipher%2Fskip32.rb

I'm currently using this patdeegan/integer-obfuscator to create a non sequential id corresponding to each of my db ids. The thing is, I need this ID to be between 0 and ((2^31)-1) and the above generates ids that go up to ((2^32)-1)

I have little understanding of bitwise operations but [this article](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20080804095748) seems to state they tweaked Skip32 to generate an integer on only 31-bit.

Does someone know how this would need to be adapted and explain it to me ?

Comment: And I assume you want the "encrypted ID" to be decryptable to the original ID?

Comment: I could do without it actually. What I need is to generate an id that would be unique based on an input integer and a specified key.